# Using Smarty loop to wrap a div around every two items

Tags: php, html, smarty

I think I am on the right track but not working as I hoped; I want to wrap every two items with a div wrapper which breaks things onto new lines every 2 items but not really working how I have done. I am rather new to Smarty.

TPL

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12">
    {foreach from=$cart.products item="pp" key="pp_key" name="loop"}
      {if $pp.extra.package_info.p_id == $key && !$pp.extra.package_info.hidden}
        <div class="span6">
          <p>{$pp.product_id|fn_specific_development_get_category}<br>
            <a href="{"products.view&product_id=`$pp.product_id`"|fn_url}">  {$pp.product}</a>
          </p>
          {if $pp.product_options}
            {include file="common/options_info.tpl" product_options=$cart_products.$pp_key.product_options}
          {else}
            &nbsp;-&nbsp;
          {/if}
          <p class="center">{$pp.amount / $product.amount}</p>
          {if $product.price_rule == "S"}
            <p>{include file="common/price.tpl" value=$pp.extra.package_info.f_price class="none"}</p>
            <p>{include file="common/price.tpl" value=$pp.extra.package_info.f_price*$pp.amount class="none"}</p>
          {/if}
        </div>
      {/if}
      {if $pp.extra.package_info.p_id == $key}
        <input type="hidden" name="cart_products[{$key}][package][{$pp.extra.package_info.table_key}][{$pp.extra.package_info.inc}][product_id]" value="{$pp.product_id}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="cart_products[{$key}][package][{$pp.extra.package_info.table_key}][{$pp.extra.package_info.inc}][amount]" value="{$pp.amount / $product.amount}" />
        {if $pp.product_options}
          {foreach from=$pp.product_options key="opt_id" item="opt_value"}
            <input type="hidden" name="cart_products[{$key}][package][{$pp.extra.package_info.table_key}][{$pp.extra.package_info.inc}][product_options][{$opt_id}]" value="{$opt_value}" />
          {/foreach}
        {/if}
      {/if}
      {if $smarty.foreach.loop.index is div by 2} 
        </div><div class="row-fluid">
      {/if}
    {/foreach}
  </div>
</div>
```

It should end up something like....

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span6">....</div>
  <div class="span6">....</div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span6">....</div>
  <div class="span6">....</div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span6">....</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else wanting to know here was my solution:

Used a iteration and strip to wrap content loop

```
{foreach from=$cart.products item="pp" key="pp_key" name="loop"}
  {strip}
    {if $pp.extra.package_info.p_id == $key && !$pp.extra.package_info.hidden}
      <div class="span6">
        <p>{$pp.product_id|fn_specific_development_get_category}<br>
          <a href="{"products.view&product_id=`$pp.product_id`"|fn_url}">  {$pp.product}</a>
        </p>
        {if $pp.product_options}
          {include file="common/options_info.tpl" product_options=$cart_products.$pp_key.product_options}
        {else}
          &nbsp;-&nbsp;
        {/if}
        <p class="center">{$pp.amount / $product.amount}</p>
        {if $product.price_rule == "S"}
          <p>{include file="common/price.tpl" value=$pp.extra.package_info.f_price class="none"}</p>
          <p>{include file="common/price.tpl" value=$pp.extra.package_info.f_price*$pp.amount class="none"}</p>
        {/if}
      </div>
    {/if}
    {if $pp.extra.package_info.p_id == $key}
      <input type="hidden" name="cart_products[{$key}][package][{$pp.extra.package_info.table_key}][{$pp.extra.package_info.inc}][product_id]" value="{$pp.product_id}" />
      <input type="hidden" name="cart_products[{$key}][package][{$pp.extra.package_info.table_key}][{$pp.extra.package_info.inc}][amount]" value="{$pp.amount / $product.amount}" />
      {if $pp.product_options}
        {foreach from=$pp.product_options key="opt_id" item="opt_value"}
          <input type="hidden" name="cart_products[{$key}][package][{$pp.extra.package_info.table_key}][{$pp.extra.package_info.inc}][product_options][{$opt_id}]" value="{$opt_value}" />
        {/foreach}
      {/if}
    {/if}
  {/strip}
  {if $smarty.foreach.loop.last or $smarty.foreach.loop.iteration is div by 2}
    </div><div class="row-fluid">
  {/if}
{/foreach}
```